# Travelling to USA for a conference and visiting relatives. Just B1, or B1/B2?

Tags: visas, b1-b2-visas

I'm travelling to the USA to present a paper at a conference. Prior to that I'll be attending another workshop and afterwards I'll be doing some work with a collaborator before returning back to India. So I definitely need the B1 visa.

However, I'll be visiting my relatives (aunt, uncle) for 2 days prior to all of this and I'll be staying with them while attending the workshop (they live close by).

Do I need to also apply for the B2 (with it's additional document requirements, etc.), or is a B1 enough for my purposes?

Comment: Most people get B1/B2 visas anyway. And given the nature of your itinerary, it would improve your chances of getting the visa to apply for it and provide the additional information.

Comment: Alright then. It now appears that I'll be spending more time with relatives, so I think I will do just that. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting a B1/B2 would easily cover both your needs and makes more sense in your case. Supplying more information would also improve your chances of getting that visa.